# Async function await not awaiting

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous

I have an async function to upload a video using MultipartRequest.
When I call my async function 'uploadVideo', by:

```
Future<List<File>> files;
                   
files.then((mediaFiles) {  
                           
   mediaFiles.forEach((element) async {  
                      
     await uploadVideo(element, userid))
                          
    });
                    
});
```

The video is uploaded but it runs the next functions before finishing the upload. Why is the await is not awaiting?

```
static Future<bool> uploadVideo(File video, int userID) async {

var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/uploadFile');

Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};

var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

request.fields['userID'] = userID.toString();

request.headers.addAll(headers);

Uint8List data = await video.readAsBytes();
List<int> list = data.cast();

request.files.add(
await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', list, filename: '.mp4'),
);

final response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT use `.forEach` with asynchronous callbacks. Instead, if you want to wait for each asynchronous callback sequentially, just use a normal for loop:

```js
for (var video in files) {
  await uploadVideo(video);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use await in

```
 request.files.add(
  await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', list, filename: '.mp4'),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , but still not working

Comment: can you please provide full code snippet, where you are calling this uploadVideo function.

Comment: `Future<List<File>> files; // upload from file picker

                      files.then((mediaFiles) {
                        if (!mediaFiles.isEmpty) {
                          mediaFiles.forEach((element) async {
                            if (await uploadVideo(element, userid)) {}
                          });
                        }
                      });`

Answer (score 0):

you can write the following statement

```
 request.send().then((response) {
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       return true;
       }
    });
```

instead of

```
final response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: can you comment line  for now : request.files.add(
await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', list, filename: '.mp4'),
);  and check

Comment: Still not working

Comment: do you have internet permission for this app ?

Comment: Yes permission has implemented in Android Manifest, All files uploaded, but the app navigate to the other screen before uploaded all files

Comment: can you share the code where you are checking files were uploaded  and navigate to other screen

Comment: `Future<List<File>> files; // upload from file picker
                      files.then((mediaFiles) {
                          mediaFiles.forEach((element) async {
                        await uploadVideo(element, userid)
                          });
                        
                      });
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => NextScreen(),
                        ),
                      );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245072/discussion-between-hadi-hawi-and-hardik-mehta).